# ist dazu/dafür gut, damit/dass

Tags: word-choice, expression, adverb, conjunction

Betrachten wir den folgenden Abschnitt:

> […] die Ferse ist verstärkt und hochgezogen. Das ist dazu gut, dass
> der Fuß besser gehalten werden kann und das Anbringen von Sporen
> möglich ist.

(Quelle: http://www.reitsport-landenhausen.de/2018/11/die-unterschiede-von-dressurstiefel-zu-springstiefel .)

Zweifelsohne kann man in diesem speziellen Fall den zweiten Satz schöner bzw. anders formulieren.  Mir geht es hingegen allgemein um die Unterscheidung der Konstrukte „dafür/dazu gut, dass/damit“ als um den Gesamtsatz.

Wie würdet ihr also den zweiten Satz beginnen und warum?

1. Das ist dazu gut, dass
2. Das ist dafür gut, dass
3. Das ist dazu gut, damit
4. Das ist dafür gut, damit

?

Andere Beispiele:

> Pacing ist dazu gut, dass Sie andere netter finden.

(Quelle: https://www.nlp-atelier-online.de/nlp-fuer-dummies .)

> Eine Lektorenrunde ist dafür gut, dass der Autor rausfindet, [...] was gut an seinem Text ist und was vielleicht nicht so. Die Lektoren helfen dabei.

(Quelle: https://www.friedrich-verlag.de/grundschule/deutsch/schreiben/die-lektorenrunde-6270 .)

> Der Termin bei Ihnen vor Ort ist dafür gut, dass wir uns einen besseren Eindruck über die technischen und räumlichen Gegebenheiten Ihres Hausen verschaffen können.

(Quelle: https://kreuz.de/heizungsmodernisierung/heizungsmodernisierung-schritte .)

> Dieser Schritt ist dafür gut, damit dein Aufkleber fest genug auf der Übertragungsfolie haftet.

(Quelle: https://www.lindaliebevoll.de/anleitung-fuer-klebeschrift-aufkleber .)

> Jeden Aktenbund mit dieser Überschrift und Benennung des Gerichts zu versehen, ist dazu gut, damit, wenn die Sache an den Oberrichter gelangt, wo Akten von allerlei Ämtern zusammen kommen, man sogleich von außen erkennen kann, wo sie hingehören.

(Quelle: https://books.google.de/books?id=SlBEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=%22ist+dazu+gut,+damit%22&source=bl&ots=O9P5sOuXhV&sig=ACfU3U1OCjmeozxrobZvhtphLZd0UhwP0A&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio-duE_Ij0AhVdgP0HHbk1CI4Q6AF6BAgREAM#v=onepage&q=%22ist%20dazu%20gut%2C%20damit%22&f=false .)

Comment: ich bin ziemlich sicher, dass es 'dafür / dazu [...], dass' heißen muss. Von dem hölzernen Klang der ganzen Formulierung einmal abgesehen. M.E. geht sowohl dafür alsauch dazu.

Comment: @Burki Danke zu „dass“. Die Konstruktion kommt in halbhormellen Dialogen oft vor: „– Wir wollen eine Anlage mit Eigenschaften (A), (B) und (C) bauen. – „Und auch (D), die dafür/dazu gut ist, dass/damit … “.

Comment: Auch da finde ich "...dazu dient, (dass) ..." die deutlich bessere Formulierung.

Comment: @Burki „dient“ statt „gut ist“ finde ich auch besser, danke.

Answer (score 1):

Alle vorgeschlagenen Varianten klingen unbeholfen, vom vermeidbaren Nebensatz ganz abgesehen.

Mein Vorschlag:

> Dadurch kann der Fuß besser gehalten werden und das Anbringen von Sporen wird möglich.

Comment: Zwar klingt dein Vorschlag zweifelsohne schöner. Mir geht es hingegen um die Unterscheidung der Konstrukte „dafür/dazu gut, dass/damit“ als um den Gesamtsatz.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Wenn du meine Antwort liest, wirst du feststellen, dass *dadurch* auf die Art und Weise verweist, die über das Mittel zum Zweck führt. In meinen Augen ist dieser Vorschlag optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe mal [eine Google Ngram Suche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=daf%C3%BCr%20dass%2Cdaf%C3%BCr%20damit%2Cdazu%20dass%2Cdazu%20damit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3#) gemacht, die ungefähr zeigt, wie häufig die verschiedenen Wendungen im Verlauf der Zeit in der Schriftsprache gebraucht wurden:

[image]

Bei aller berechtigter Kritik an den Daten, sieht man doch sehr schön, dass die Wendungen mit *dass* deutlich überwiegen und dass die häufigste Wendung *dafür, dass* ist.

Soviel zum (schriftlichen) Sprachgebrauch, wobei man natürlich davon ausgehen muss, dass manche der Schreiber nicht korrekt geschrieben haben. So erklären sich vielleicht auch die Funde mit *damit*, denn sowohl *dafür, damit* als auch *dazu, damit* sind falsch.

Denn *[dafür](https://www.dwds.de/wb/daf%C3%BCr)* und *[dazu](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dazu)* bedeuten bereits "für diesen Zweck", und *[damit](https://www.dwds.de/wb/damit#2)* bedeutet noch einmal dasselbe, nämlich "zu dem Zwecke, dass". Demnach bedeutet eine Fügung wie *Das ist dazu gut, damit ...* soviel wie "Das ist für den Zweck gut, zu dem Zweck, dass ...". Und das ist eben Unsinn.

Ob du *dafür* oder *dazu* verwenden magst, ist meiner Meinung nach Geschmacksache. Beide Wörter sind in dieser Verwendung synonym und korrekt. Im Zweifelsfall richte ich mich nach der Häufigkeit und verwende die häufigere Form, da diese von mehr Sprechern als wohlklingend erlebt wird.

---

Grundsätzlich wäre ich mit Belegen aus dem Internet immer vorsichtig. Webseitenbetreiber wie ein Heizungsmonteur können nicht zwangsläufig gut und richtig Deutsch, und manche Bücher, wie das von dir zitierte *NLP für Dummies*, sind hölzern oder gar falsch aus einer Fremdsprache übersetzt. Stilistisch sichere und grammatisch korrekte Sprache findet man eher in überregionalen Zeitungen oder literarischen Werken. Je mehr Lektorat hinter einer Publikation steckt, desto beispielhafter ist ihr Sprachgebrauch in der Regel.

Comment: Danke! Na ja, es hätte ja sein können, dass es einen leichten semantischen oder stilistischen Unterschied zwischen „für etwas gut sein“ und „zu etwas gut sein“ gäbe. Bei Zeitungen beachte, dass sie öfter Platzproblemen zweier Art unterlegen. Als Verfasser würde ich da immer zu „dazu“ greifen, wenn ich mehr sagen will als ich Platz hab, und zu „dafür“, wenn ich nichts sagen kann aber Platz belegen muss/will. Gerade deswegen rückte man übrigens in Großbritannien vor über hundert Jahren vom seriellen Komma ab: die Beiträge hatten zu wenig Platz!

Answer (score 0):

### Dafür

beantwortet die Frage nach dem Zweck.

> **Wofür** ist das gut?.
> X ist dafür gut, dass ...

### Dazu

beantwortet die Frage nach der Wirkung.

> Wozu ist das gut?
> X führt dazu, dass ...
> X dient dazu, dass ...

### Damit

beantwortet die Frage nach dem Mittel (womit). Es ist kein Ersatz für *dass* und in beiden Fällen einfach falsch, auch wenn es umgangssprachlich teilweise als Ersatz für *dass* verwendet wird.